# Convert a String to Map(String, List([Int,Int]))

Tags: scala

I am currently learning Scala and I am trying to read lines of text from a file and convert them into a map of type - `Map[String, List[(Int,Int)]]`, but having difficulty getting there.

Example of text from file = `London, -1:19, -2:21, 0:18, -3:24`

I want it to be returned as - `Map(London -> List((-1,19), (-2,21), (0,18), (-3,24))`

I am able to get the city name by doing:

```
for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines()) {
        val splitLine = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
        val city = splitLine.head
```

But I'm not able to get much further after this, I can't split the rest of the values into a list of ints.

EDIT:

Adding the full method in for clarification

```
def readFile(filename: String): Map[String, List[(Int, Int)]] = {
    val result = for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines(); array = line.split(",").map(_.trim)) yield Map(array.head -> array.tail.map(x => {
      val y = x.split(":"); (y(0).toInt, y(1).toInt)
    }).toList)
    result
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can do that in one line* as

```
val result = for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines(); array = line.split(",").map(_.trim)) yield Map(array.head -> array.tail.map(x => {val y = x.split(":"); (y(0).toInt, y(1).toInt)}).toList)
```

`result` should be

```
Map(London -> List((-1,19), (-2,21), (0,18), (-3,24)))
//Iterator[Map[String, (Int, Int}]]
```

`result` is an `Iterator` so you should change the return type accordingly

```
def readFile(filename: String): Iterator[Map[String, List[(Int, Int)]]] = {
    val result = for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines(); array = line.split(",").map(_.trim)) yield Map(array.head -> array.tail.map(x => {
      val y = x.split(":"); (y(0).toInt, y(1).toInt)
    }).toList)
    result
  }
```

**Iterators are not really a collection and are not safe** so I would suggest you to return list instead as

```
def readFile(filename: String): List[Map[String, List[(Int, Int)]]] = {
  val result = for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines(); array = line.split(",").map(_.trim)) yield Map(array.head -> array.tail.map(x => {
    val y = x.split(":"); (y(0).toInt, y(1).toInt)
  }).toList)
  result.toList
}
```

Your comments suggested that you want

> Not really how I would like it displayed as other cities added to the file will give me an output like: `List(Map(London -> List((-1,19), (-2,21), (0,18), (-3,24))), Map(Edinburgh -> List((-3,16), (-2, 19), (-1, 21)))` etc... instead of `Map(London -> List((-1,19), (-2,21), (0,18), (-3,24))), Edinburgh -> List((-3,16), (-2, 19), (-1, 21)))` almost like a key/value pair

For that all you need is `.flatter.toMap` and change the return type to `Map[String, List[(Int, Int)]]`

```
def readFile(filename: String): Map[String, List[(Int, Int)]] = {
  val result = for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines(); array = line.split(",").map(_.trim)) yield Map(array.head -> array.tail.map(x => {
    val y = x.split(":"); (y(0).toInt, y(1).toInt)
  }).toList)
  result.toList.flatten.toMap
}
```

Comment: Have tried this solution, but get an error for "non-empty iterator", I have added an edit with the full method of what I'm trying to do

Comment: you should try my method, did you ?

Comment: Yes I tried your method and it does seem the best way to do this, but the error I am getting is "Expression of type Iterator[Map[String, List[(Int,Int)]]] does not conform to expected type Map[String, List[(Int,Int)]]" - Added the code with your method in OP

Comment: Those changes work, thanks! Not really how I would like it displayed as other cities added to the file will give me an output like: `List(Map(London -> List((-1,19), (-2,21), (0,18), (-3,24))), Map(Edinburgh -> List((-3,16), (-2, 19), (-1, 21))) etc...` instead of `Map(London -> List((-1,19), (-2,21), (0,18), (-3,24))), Edinburgh -> List((-3,16), (-2, 19), (-1, 21)))` almost like a key/value pair

Comment: Thank you, that worked great! :) I haven't came across flatten yet, but after reading the docs on it it makes perfect sense to use it! Thanks again

Comment: But why would you want to do it in one line?

Comment: @nmat one line is just a possibility. Its not that important. Clear and concise is important while coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows to get a `Map[String,List[(Int, Int)]]]` as you requested

```
for {
 line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines()
 val array = line.split(",")
}yield Map(array.head -> array.tail.toList.map(_.split(":").map(_.trim.toInt)).map(elem => (elem(0), elem(1))))
```

The biggest logic is in the tail management, to turn it to a tuple of Ints